# Noetherian Ring and Homomorphic Image

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, noetherian

Prove that, if $R$ is Noetherian, then so is each homomorphic image of $R$.

I know that by the Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem this is the same as showing that if $R$ is Noetherian, then so is $R/I$ for each proper ideal $I$, which I think I can use the correspondence theorem for this.

I am struggling piecing together how to write the proof though. Any help would be great!

Comment: It’s just that if $R\to S$ is a ring morphism that’s onto, then $S\cong R/I$ where $I$ is the kernel of your morphism.

Comment: There is a one-to-one correspondence between ideals of $R$ containing $I$, with ideals of $R/I$. Also, if an ideal of $R$ is finitely generated, then its image in $R/I$ will also be finitely generated